# Android Phonegap App - Close & stop app on exit

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to stop an app on exit?  I have the following code within Phonegap to monitor back button clicks and I would like it to stop the app when exiting - if possible?

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true); 


function backKeyDown() { 

    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
      setTimeout( function() {navigator.app.exitApp();}, 100 );

    }
    else {
        setTimeout( function() {$.mobile.changePage("#homepage");}, 100 );

    }
}
```

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Paul, navigator.app.exitApp() will cause your application to stop executing. Is this not the behaviour you are seeing?

Answer (score -2):

Below method may be useful to you.

```
BackButton.override();
BackButton.exitApp();
```

Comment: These methods are for very old versions of PhoneGap.